# Can I add a curved trend line to a ggplot with only one data point per column?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have used ggplot2 to create a line graph for a soil water release curve. However, because I only have one data point at each pressure value (the x axis), the lines are connected directly from point to point. I would like to keep the points but have a curve that shows the trend of the points. This is the typical style for soil water release curves.

Data:

```
> dput(head(sub2018))
structure(list(Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = 
c("2018", 
"2019"), class = "factor"), Pressure = structure(1:6, .Label = c("-1", 
"-0.5", "-0.25", "-0.2", "-0.1", "-0.05", "-0.02", "-0.01", "0"
), class = "factor"), meanVWC = c(0.291819594, 0.308328767666667, 
0.318496127666667, 0.323671866333333, 0.349356212666667, 
0.374201803666667
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "Year", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
0:5), group_sizes = 6L, biggest_group_size = 6L, labels = structure(list(
Year = structure(1L, .Label = c("2018", "2019"), class = "factor")),             
row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame", vars = "Year", drop = TRUE))
```

ggplot:

```
GGplot2018 <- ggplot(sub2018, aes(x=Pressure, y=meanVWC, group=1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() + labs(y= "Volumetric Water Content") 
GGplot2018
```

Does anyone know if/how I can add this curve?

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
GGplot2018 <- ggplot(sub2018, aes(x=Pressure, y=meanVWC, group=1)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point() + labs(y= "Volumetric Water Content")+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",se = FALSE)
GGplot2018
```

Comment: I think that that geom_smooth function just gives me a straight line. Is there any way to have it follow the curve that the data is suggesting? Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: @Trev No problem! It's giving you a straight line because that's the trend of your data.